# QGIS 2.14 - Processing Toolbox slow

Tags: performance, qgis-processing

Since installing 2.14 (and manually fixing errors with MSYS / Grass 7 carryover from previous installation of 2.12), when I try to search for a command in processing toolbox it appears to be re-indexing the available tools and causes a significant delay (say 40 secs +) before starting to display matching results.

I also have advisories confirmign that I can add more algorithms to the toolbox (referring to Grass 6) which I don't need, given I have Grass 7 activated.

How can I improve performance in accessing processing toolbox algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in version 2.14. It will be fixed when 2.14.2 is released.